Angularfire analatyics got initialized but I don't see my logged events in Firebase console
I'm new to Firebase Analytics... But I could successfully install (npm install firebase @angular/fire) AngularFire in my app.
app.config.ts file:
import { provideFirebaseApp, initializeApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { getAnalytics, provideAnalytics } from '@angular/fire/analytics';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideFirebaseApp(() =>
      initializeApp({
        apiKey: 'xxx',
        authDomain: 'xxx.firebaseapp.com',
        databaseURL: 'https://xxx.firebaseio.com',
        projectId: 'xxx',
        storageBucket: 'xxx',
        messagingSenderId: '123',
        appId: 'xxx',
        measurementId: 'xxx',
      }),
    ),
    provideAnalytics(() => getAnalytics()),
    ...
  ],
  ...
})

app.component.ts file:
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Analytics, logEvent } from '@angular/fire/analytics';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  private _analytics = inject(Analytics);
  
  constructor() {
    logEvent(this._analytics, 'app_open', { component: 'AppComponent' })
  }
}

I don't see my event (app_open) is logged in the 'DebugView' of my Firebase project... In that page, I also see this message: 'Debug Device: 0, No devices available', although I have already installed 'Google Analytics Debugger' Chrome extension and turned it on. Am I missing something?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Regarding receiving unnecessary heartbeats undefined console logs, I just saw this ticket. It seems that this issue is fixed in '10.13.1' version of the Firebase JS SDK.
